# C# - amend values from column1 in DaraGridView and put them in new column

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, split

I have a section of code which splits an input string into rows and outputs it into a DataGridView.

These are all populated into column 1.

I want to further split the values in column 1 into column 2 and 3 etc.

**The values for column 2 and 3 need to come from column 1 NOT THE ORIGINAL INPUT**.

For example:

**EDIT: More example inputs**

Input String :

```
abc12, def, 56, jkl78, mno90
```

Current Code:

```
private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<string> eSplit = new List<string>(eInputBox.Text.Split(new string[] { "," }, StringSplitOptions.None));

    DataGridViewTextBoxColumn eOutputGrid = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
    eOutputGrid.HeaderText = "Section";
    eOutputGrid.Name = "Section";
    eOutputDGV.Columns.Add(eOutputGrid);
    foreach (string item in eSplit)
    {
        eOutputDGV.Rows.Add(item);
    }
 }
```

Desired Output: (if there is no value then it needs to be blank).

```
Section  Letters  Numbers
abc12    abc      12
def      def      
56                56
jkl78    jkl      78
mno90    mno      90
```

Comment: Use a linq query and shape output result using `Select`. Or if you are more into using `foreach` loop, create a new model containing those `Section`, `Letters` and `Numbers` and add it to a list.

Comment: If I understand correctly, what you are aiming for is not doable, to have "window" into the first cell, without creating separate string value per each cell. You will have distinct string variables in each column one way or another. You can implement `VirtualMode` and fill columns based on `eSplit` using `CellValueNeeded` event, or using helper class like @RezaAghaei suggested, but result in the cell will be new variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add each column definition to your `eOutputDGV` and then to pass three parameters to each `eOutputDGV.Row`:

```cs
private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<string> eSplit = new List<string>(eInputBox.Text.Split(new string[] { "," }, StringSplitOptions.None));

    DataGridViewTextBoxColumn eOutputGrid = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
    eOutputGrid.HeaderText = "Section";
    eOutputGrid.Name = "Section";
    eOutputDGV.Columns.Add(eOutputGrid);

    eOutputGrid = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
    eOutputGrid.HeaderText = "Letters";
    eOutputGrid.Name = "Letters";
    eOutputDGV.Columns.Add(eOutputGrid);

    eOutputGrid = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
    eOutputGrid.HeaderText = "Numbers";
    eOutputGrid.Name = "Numbers";
    eOutputDGV.Columns.Add(eOutputGrid);

    foreach (string item in eSplit)
    {
        eOutputDGV.Rows.Add(item.Trim(), item.Trim().Substring(0, 3), item.Trim().Substring(3));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a list of string, you can shape it into the expected result using a linq query:

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = list.Select(x=>Process(x)).ToList();
```

And what is the `Process` method? It's a static method which is responsible to process the input string and convert it to the desired model, let's say you have a model like this:

```
public class MyModel
{
    public string Letters { get; set; }
    public int Numbers { get; set; }
    public string Section
    {
        get
        {
            return $"{Letters}{Numbers}";
        }
    }
}
```

Then the process method is something like this:

```
pubic static MyModel Process(string s)
{
    // some logic to extract information form `s`
    return new MyModel(){ Letters = ..., Numbers = ... };
}
```

Comment: Updated my question for clarity

Answer (score 1):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace dgvAlphaNumbericSplit
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();

            dataGridView1.Rows.Add("abc12", "", "");
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add("def", "", "");
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add("56", "", "");
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add("jkl78", "", "");
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add("mno90", "", "");
        }

        private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
            {
                if(dataGridView1.Rows[row.Index].Cells[0].Value != null)
                {
                    string str = dataGridView1.Rows[row.Index].Cells[0].Value.ToString();

                    int index = str.IndexOfAny(new char[] { '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9' });

                    string chars = "";
                    string nums = "";

                    if (index >= 0)
                    {
                        chars = str.Substring(0, index);

                        nums = str.Substring(index);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        chars = str;
                    }

                    dataGridView1.Rows[row.Index].Cells[1].Value = chars;
                    dataGridView1.Rows[row.Index].Cells[2].Value = nums;

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here are the results: -

[image]