# C# Using data from DataGridView in a Chart

Tags: c#, winforms, charts, datagridview

I have code that generates data in the DataGridView and I want to also push this to  a chart from the same button click.

Process:

Text is put into a text box `myInputBox` then the button `processButton` is pressed to split the text up and output it to the DataGridView `myOutputDGV` the button has the following code:

```
private void processButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            List<string> mySplit = new List<string>(myInputBox.Text.Split(new string[] { "XN" }, StringSplitOptions.None));

            DataGridViewTextBoxColumn myOutputGrid = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
            myOutputGrid.HeaderText = "Line";
            myOutputGrid.Name = "Line";
            myOutputDGV.Columns.Add(myOutputGrid);
            myOutputGrid = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();

            myOutputGrid.HeaderText = "Section";
            myOutputGrid.Name = "Section";
            myOutputDGV.Columns.Add(myOutputGrid);
            myOutputGrid = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();

            myOutputGrid.HeaderText = "Range";
            myOutputGrid.Name = "Range";
            myOutputDGV.Columns.Add(myOutputGrid);
            myOutputGrid = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();

            myOutputGrid.HeaderText = "Total";
            myOutputGrid.Name = "Total";
            myOutputDGV.Columns.Add(myOutputGrid);
            myOutputGrid = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();

            foreach (string item in mySplit)
            {
                myOutputDGV.Rows.Add(item.Trim(),
                item.Split(new string[] { "(cost=" }, StringSplitOptions.None).First(),
                Regex.Match(item, @"cost=(.+?) rows").Groups[1].Value,
                Regex.Match(item, @"cost=(.+?)\.\.").Groups[1].Value,
            }
        }
```

I want to populate my chart `myChart` with the values from column[1] (Line) on the X axis and column[3] (Total) on the Y axis.

**EDIT:**

I have tried adding the following code in the button `processButton` click code but the chart isn't populated:

```
ChartArea chartArea1 = new ChartArea();
chartArea1.AxisX.MajorGrid.LineColor = Color.LightGray;
chartArea1.AxisY.MajorGrid.LineColor = Color.LightGray;
chartArea1.AxisX.LabelStyle.Font = new Font("Consolas", 8);
chartArea1.AxisY.LabelStyle.Font = new Font("Consolas", 8);
myChart.ChartAreas.Add(chartArea1);

myChart.Series.Add(new Series());

myChart.Series[0].XValueMember = myOutputDGV.Columns[1].DataPropertyName;
myChart.Series[0].YValueMembers = myOutputDGV.Columns[3].DataPropertyName;
myChart.DataSource = myOutputDGV.DataSource;

myChart.Series[0].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
```

**EDIT 2:**

I have also tried this to no avail:

```
System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartArea myChartArea = new System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartArea();
myChartArea.AxisX.MajorGrid.LineColor = Color.Red;
myChartArea.AxisY.MajorGrid.LineColor = Color.Red;
myChartArea.AxisX.LabelStyle.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Consolas", 10);
myChartArea.AxisY.LabelStyle.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Consolas", 10);
myChart.ChartAreas.Add(myChartArea);

myChart.Series.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Series());

var datax = myOutputDGV.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>().Select(x => x.Cells[1].Value).ToList();
var datay = myOutputDGV.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>().Select(x => x.Cells[4].Value).ToList();
```

**EDIT 3 FULL CODE:**

```
private void ProcessButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(myInputBox.Text) || myInputBox.Text == "")
{
    MessageBox.Show("Please enter data", "Info");
}
else
{
    myOutputDGV.Rows.Clear();
    myOutputDGV.Columns.Clear();
    myOutputDGV.Refresh();
    myChart.ChartAreas.Clear();
    myChart.Series.Clear();

    List<string> mySplit = new List<string>(myInputBox.Text.Split(new string[] { "XN" }, StringSplitOptions.None));

    DataGridViewTextBoxColumn myOutputGrid = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
    myOutputGrid.HeaderText = "Line";
    myOutputGrid.Name = "Line";
    myOutputDGV.Columns.Add(myOutputGrid);
    myOutputGrid = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();

    myOutputGrid.HeaderText = "Section";
    myOutputGrid.Name = "Section";
    myOutputDGV.Columns.Add(myOutputGrid);
    myOutputGrid = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();

    myOutputGrid.HeaderText = "Cost Range";
    myOutputGrid.Name = "Cost Range";
    myOutputDGV.Columns.Add(myOutputGrid);
    myOutputGrid = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();

    myOutputGrid.HeaderText = "Cost First Row";
    myOutputGrid.Name = "Cost First Row";
    myOutputDGV.Columns.Add(myOutputGrid);
    myOutputGrid = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();

    myOutputGrid.HeaderText = "Cost All Rows";
    myOutputGrid.Name = "Cost All Rows";
    myOutputDGV.Columns.Add(myOutputGrid);
    myOutputGrid = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();

    myOutputGrid.HeaderText = "Rows";
    myOutputGrid.Name = "Rows";
    myOutputDGV.Columns.Add(myOutputGrid);
    myOutputGrid = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();

    myOutputGrid.HeaderText = "Width";
    myOutputGrid.Name = "Width";
    myOutputDGV.Columns.Add(myOutputGrid);

    foreach (string item in mySplit)
    {
        myOutputDGV.Rows.Add(item.Trim(),
        item.Split(new string[] { "(cost=" }, StringSplitOptions.None).First(),
        Regex.Match(item, @"cost=(.+?) rows").Groups[1].Value,
        Regex.Match(item, @"cost=(.+?)\.\.").Groups[1].Value,
        Regex.Match(item, @"\.\.(.+?) ").Groups[1].Value,
        Regex.Match(item, @"rows=(.+?) ").Groups[1].Value,
        Regex.Match(item, @"width=(.+?)\)").Groups[1].Value);
    }

    var datax = myOutputDGV.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>().Select(x => x.Cells[1].Value).ToList();
    var datay = myOutputDGV.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>().Select(x => x.Cells[4].Value).ToList();
    System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartArea myChartArea = new System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartArea();
    myChartArea.AxisX.MajorGrid.LineColor = Color.Red;
    myChartArea.AxisY.MajorGrid.LineColor = Color.Red;
    myChartArea.AxisX.LabelStyle.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Consolas", 10);
    myChartArea.AxisY.LabelStyle.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Consolas", 10);
    myChart.ChartAreas.Add(myChartArea);
    myChart.Series.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Series());

    myChart.Series[0].XValueMember = myOutputDGV.Columns[1].DataPropertyName;
    myChart.Series[0].YValueMembers = myOutputDGV.Columns[3].DataPropertyName;
    myChart.DataSource = myOutputDGV.DataSource;
    myChart.Series.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Series());
}
}
```

**EDIT 4 i have grids and half a line:**

```
            var datax = myOutputDGV.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>().Select(x => x.Cells[1].Value).ToList();
            var datay = myOutputDGV.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>().Select(x => x.Cells[4].Value).ToList();
            string dataxx = datax.ToString();
            string datayy = datay.ToString();
            System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartArea myChartArea = new System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartArea();
            myChart.ChartAreas.Add(myChartArea);
            myChart.Series.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Series());
            myChart.Series[0].Points.AddXY(dataxx, datayy);
```

Comment: Use a datasource for the `DataGridView`. A `DataTable` or a `List<T>` or `BinsingList<T>` where T is a model containing properties which you want to have in `DataGridView`. Then you can easily show data in chart as well.

Comment: @RezaAghaei Thank you for the comment, I think you are overestimating my ability in C# :) I don't know how to do that.

Comment: I shared an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57553654/3110834) in your previous question. You can use the same approach here as well. Then those column definitions or manually adding rows are not needed. You can easily set `DataSource` of `DataGridView`.

Comment: Yes, I couldn't get that to work for what I needed in the first question.

Comment: You need to start working with data-binding and using `DataSource` of `DataGridView`. Try using the same approach here, you just need to refactor your code a bit. The model should contain `Line`, `Section`, `Range` and `Total` properties. The logic which you have inside the for loop, is the logic which creates an instance of the model. Using a linq `Select` statement, you can create a `List` of your model from `mySplit`. Then just set the result as `DataSource` of the `DataGridView`, without adding columns/rows manually.

Comment: But in the case of how it has been done currently, is it possible to put it into a chart?

Comment: `chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(xvalue, yvalue)`

Comment: @RezaAghaei I have updated my question with what i have for the chart creation

Comment: Did you assign any value to `myOutputDGV.DataSource`? I guess no, because your approach is adding rows manually which is totally different from data source approach.

Comment: How and where do I assign that value?

Comment: It's been described in my comments above. Read them and if you want to use `DataSource` follow them. In case you don't want to follow those comments, modify your chart-related code to add chart point using `chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(xvalue, yvalue)` in for loop, the same way you added  rows to DGV.

Comment: Where would i add `chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(xvalue, yvalue)` also i tried `myChart.Series[0].Points.AddXY(Column[1], Column[3])` and i get errors on the columns.

Comment: Well, the @RezaAghaei advice is the best option, but if you insist on keeping the code as close as you have it, then define `DataTable`, add columns and use your code to fill the `DataTable`. Then assign it as a `DataSource` to both `DataGridView` and the `Chart`.

Comment: You are using DataPropertyName but the DGV doesn't seem to be databound so this makes no sense!

Comment: @TaW Yup, makes even less sense to me, don't know how to do this at all hence the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to preserve your code as much as possible, you can fill a `DataTable` instead of the `DataGridView` and use that as the `DataSource` in both the `DataGridView` and `Chart`.

Following code is roughly what you need to do for this case: Declare the `DataTable`, create `Columns` (of correct types, I just guessed them!), fill the `Rows`, and use it as `DataSource`.

The benefits are clear: You will have forced data-types and you can use a breakpoint and VS Data Visualizer to check, if the content looks as expected (but you'll see it in this case in `DataGridView` too). It might be the data type giving you a trouble in the `chart`.

C# (translated):

```
private DataTable dt;

private void MyForm_Load()
{
    LoadDefaults();
}

private void LoadDefaults()
{
    dt.Columns.Add("Line", typeof(Int16));
    dt.Columns.Add("Section", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("Range", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("Total", typeof(float));
}

private void processButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

foreach (var Item in mySplit) {
    dt.Rows.Add({Item.Trim(), ......});
    }


this.DataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
...
myChart.DataSource = dt;
}
```

VB.NET

```
Dim dt As DataTable

Private Sub MyForm_Load()
    Call LoadDefaults()
End Sub

Private Sub LoadDefaults()
    dt.Columns.Add("Line", GetType(Int16))
    dt.Columns.Add("Section", GetType(String))
    dt.Columns.Add("Range", GetType(String))
    dt.Columns.Add("Total", GetType(Single))
End Sub

Private Sub processButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnExcel.Click
    For Each Item In mySplit
        dt.Rows.Add({Item.Trim(), Item.Split("(cost=", StringSplitOptions.None).First(), Regex.Match(Item, @"cost=(.+?) rows").Groups[1].Value, Regex.Match(Item, @"cost=(.+?)\.\.").Groups[1].Value})
    Next

    Me.DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
    ...
    myChart.DataSource = dt
End Sub
```

**EDIT** - debugging charts example:

[image]

Comment: I dont want to use a datatable, I want to do this from a DGV, is this possible?

Comment: I believe it is possible, provided you check your data types and do conversions, if required. What I propose is nearly identical, needs very little code change and is way more robust and clean.With DGV, one extra space in an "integer" could give you a day headache (BTW I don't like the string operations either, but I guess you have serious reasons for them). So why do you need to use DGV? That is important question.

Comment: Cant get this to work with my current code at all, not sure what more i need to add but still get nothing on the chart

Comment: But that's quite uninformative... Where did you get with your debugging to? Do you see the correct data values in `myChart.Series[0]`, when you place a break point bellow `Add` statement?

Comment: I dont get any errors as such (see code in EDIT2) i also dont get any values in the chart, literally just says Series1

Comment: I understand that, but what you got from debugging? How far did you get, tracking the data in debug mode, placing break points? All the way to the end - `myChart.Series[0]`? When placing cursor over this object, do you see correct values? If you use points method, of course look behind `DataBindXY(X,Y)`.

Comment: I haven't debugged anything, there is nothing to debug, just a blank chart

Comment: I added an example screenshot, what I mean. You can either follow your data from beginning to end, or start at end and if the data aren't valid, go backwards until you find where they appear correct. Especially with the wild string operation, you need to check the validity of the data. I added an example screenshot. That is, what you need to get on the `Series[0]` when you're done with adding points. If there are correct points, then you know it's probably formatting, remove all your chart formatting and if successful, continue with adding it one by one back.

Comment: I dont even know how to use the code you gave to convert it to what i need, i literally just want to say Xaxis = column[1]  Yaxis = Column[4] and it appear on the chart

Comment: Yep, OK, just start with what you have. We don't know where the problem is, still. So place a breakpoint at the end of your procedure somewere after `Series[0].Add` or `Series[0].DataBindXY(X,Y)` (depending on the method you use), run your program and when it stops on the breakpoint, hover over the nearest `Series[0]` above - like in the screenshot I added. There list down to the `Points`. What do you see? You should see alist like I have in the screenshot.

Comment: hovering over series [0] or Columns[1] doesnt give me a pop up

Comment: Then your breakpoint is set incorrectly, you just need to place it in the right place in your code: After you assign the data and before the procedure is finished. You have to at least get empty list of points and zero point count (see `Count = 14` in the screenshot, on the `Points` line). There's one more possibility and that is, that the part of code you're hovering over is not executed (i.e. in unexecuted part of `IF` condition). I see you're not very familiar with VS debugging, but there's no feasible way around this and it will certainly be a benefit for you, if you get used to it.

Comment: Let me put the full code i have in my question and see where i need the break

Comment: I believe you need it at 2nd last line, the "}". Since I don't really code C#, I'm not 100% sure, but it should be equal to "End" keyword and should work. Then hovering above, you have to get the access to `Series[0]`. If you worked with `DataTable`, you could show it as a table during debuggin, using DataTable Visualizer (a small magnifying glass icon appears over any DataTable). It's still accessible via `DataGridView`'s `DataSource`, but quite burried in the debugging tree. I suspect the data is the problem, in your case. But you can start with the `Series[0]` points.

Comment: hovering over series then going to points there only things under that are count = 0

Comment: I have added edit4, this code is giving me axis's now

Comment: That's what I expected. It's not the `Chart` what's wrong, it's your input data, which are very unreliably fetched, not providing a valid data source. I've just realized, you're using `var` DataType for your X|Y point lists. This is really problematic, and the next `.ToString()` is even worse. You want your chart to display some figures, but you provide strings. You need to figure out what you want (Single, Integer, Date,...) and set the datatype accordingly, and make sure you parse whatever you feed acordingly. Anyway, you can place break point on  `myChart` line and look into `dataX`|Y list

Comment: Could you send me a sample of the input data? I'd look into it from scratch.

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to use [Chart DataBinding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dd456766%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). - I suggest, when binding, not to bind to the chart but to the `Points` of a `Series`! - 
This way you can control things better, like choosing which `Series` to bind to.

An example..:

```
var datax = dataGridView1.Rows
            .Cast<DataGridViewRow>().Select(x => x.Cells[ixName].Value).ToList();
var datay = dataGridView1.Rows
            .Cast<DataGridViewRow>().Select(x => x.Cells[yName].Value).ToList();

aSeries.Points.DataBindXY(datax, datay);
```

..where `xName` and `yName` can be names or indices of the DGV `Columns`.

But, as has been suggested, using a `DataTable` is recommended. In any case you need an `IEnumerable` to bind.